# Is there a meaningful way to define $ij$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit and $j$ is the split-complex unit?

Tags: complex-numbers, split-complex-numbers

At the moment I'm treating $ij=ji$ as its own quantity and reducing it where possible, as in $(ij)^2 =-1$ and $e^{ij} = \cos(j) + i\sin(j) = \cosh(i) + j \sinh(i)$.

From the first identity seems like you can say $ij=\sqrt{-1}=i$, and this even agrees with  $\cos(j) + i\sin(j)= \cos(1) + i\sin(1)$ and  $\cosh(i) + j \sinh(i) = \cosh(i) + 1\sinh(i)$ unless I made a mistake, but it still seems like a strange definition.

So, Is there a way to represent $ij$ as a linear combination of $1$, $i$, and $j$, and does the definition I came up with here break anything I haven't noticed?

Comment: Since $j^2=1$, it is obviously not the case even in the split-complex numbers that if $x^2=a^2$ then $x=\pm a$. So there is no reason to assume $ij=i$ just because $(ij)^2=i^2$.

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't have disregarded the negative solution, but if we say $ij = \pm i$ what mistake am I making?

Comment: You are assume that because $(ij)^2=-1=i^2$ thatn $ij=\pm i$. This is not true for the "real" split complex numbers, since $j^2=1=1^2$, but $j\neq \pm 1$. So there is no reason to assume it is true when you add in $i$ . (It is also not 100% obvious you should be assuming $ij=ji$, but that's a whole 'nother kettle of fish.)

Comment: If you want to assume $ij=ji$, I think you will inevitably be led to the [bicomplex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicomplex_number). Or you could assume $ij=-ji$, in which case you would instead end up considering [split-quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-quaternion).

Comment: Right, so really my possible solutions to $x^2 =-1$ are $i,-i, ij,-ij$ and I was assuming too much by using that to justify $ij=i$? Do you think there is a way to represent $ij$ as a linear combination of $1,i,j$, or would I necessarily need to add a new element like in the bicomplex numbers and split-quaternions that were linked? Also, what reason is there to suspect $ij$ is not commutative?

Answer (score 1):

No. What you are talking about is tessarines, a 4-dimensional algebra that combines complex and split-complex numbers.

In that system $ij$ is a separate unit vector, similar to $i$ in that $(ij)^2=-1$. But not equal to $i$. It is irreducible.

The algebra of tessarines is commutative and associative.